CodeBlocks Isn't Running On MacOs
I have been struggling to install CodeBlocks. After many attempts and watching some YouTube videos, I finally managed to install it. However, now I'm encountering a problem. When I open it, all I see is a white screen continuously loading. What can I do to resolve this issue and make CodeBlocks work?
enter image description here
I did not know what to do.

According to their website, the last release they had for Code Blocks was 13.12, and you seem to have installed 17.something. The download page even mentions that the latest version is not available due to issues on Macos. As such, I would lean towards there being a good reason for why nothing beyond 13.12 is available. Did you try that version? Maybe the whole thing stopped working on Apple M series hardware and you have one of those?

Yes, I have m2 version. I also tried to install the 13.12 one, but for that version, It says that isn't for my operation system, like it is for windows or probably the old version of macOS systems.

If they haven't released a new version for M series machines, I'm not surprised it doesn't work. Rosetta can only do so much.
